# Why does my marque not follow my image?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

When adding an image as a SubView to another `UIImageView`, I am adding a marque over the new image that should follow as it is being edited **(moved, zoom in/out, rotate)**.

I can not get the marque to stay connected to the frame of the new image though.  **It is initially connected when the image is added but once moved the marque goes away from the image frame.**

Here is my code:

```
 **viewDidLoad:**
 if (!_marque)
 {
    _marque = [[CAShapeLayer layer] retain];
    _marque.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _marque.strokeColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] CGColor];
    _marque.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    _marque.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    _marque.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
    _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(_stampedImageView.frame.origin.x, _stampedImageView.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
    _marque.position = CGPointMake(_stampedImageView.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.origin.x, _stampedImageView.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.origin.y);
 }
 [[_stampedImageView layer] addSublayer:_marque];

 **marque Method:**
 if (![_marque actionForKey:@"linePhase"])
 {
    CABasicAnimation *dashAnimation;
    dashAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"lineDashPhase"];
    [dashAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
    [dashAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [_marque addAnimation:dashAnimation forKey:@"linePhase"];
 }

_marque.bounds = CGRectMake(_stampedImageView.frame.origin.x, _stampedImageView.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
_marque.position = CGPointMake(_stampedImageView.frame.origin.x, _stampedImageView.frame.origin.y);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, frame);
[_marque setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);

_marque.hidden = NO;

 **panGestureRecognizer:**
 CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    _firstX = [_stampedImageView center].x;
    _firstY = [_stampedImageView center].y;
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[_stampedImageView setCenter:translatedPoint];
[self showOverlayWithFrame:_stampedImageView.frame];
```

Could someone help me see what I am missing please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have an error in this line:

```
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, frame);
```

You haven't defined frame anywhere that I can see.  Maybe _stampedImageView.frame?

Comment: Frame comes from the method:  -(void)showOverlayWithFrame:(CGRect)frame